Rust - Passing Rc<> references between different structs
I'm currrently trying to implement a data structure which requires its instantiator to pass a reference to itself. I've heard about using Rc<> in these situations to avoid lifetime limitations, though I'm not entirely sure how to implement it in this particular structure.
The "parent" looks like this:
pub struct ModuleFile {
    /// Info relating to how the other fields should be read.
    pub header: ModuleHeader,
    /// Metadata regarding compression and layout of files (tags)
    pub files: Vec<ModuleFileEntry>,
    /* others */
}

And the "ModuleFileEntry" should include a reference to its respective ModuleFile:
pub struct ModuleFileEntry {
    pub module: Rc<ModuleFile>,
    pub unknown: u8,
    pub flags: FileEntryFlags,
 }

I've never properly worked with reference counting before, so this is more of a "How can I" question- or if there's a better approach to what I'm trying to do.

Self referential structs are notoriously hard to do in Rust (and often times it is impossible to do this safetly). You can use reference counted pointers to do this, but remember to not create any cycles, otherwise you will leak memory. Standard pattern here is that "parent" holds Rc to its children, and children hold Weak pointer to the parent.

@AleksanderKrauze Thank you, I'll check that out. If I recall correctly, the underlying logic of Rc and Weak makes it unsafe?

@Surasia no, implementing Rc and it's Weak is unsafe (but already done in std), using them is not.

Rc
Rc is like a immutable reference, you can have a lot of it but it is not mutable. Once you put your struct into an Rc<T> you cannot mutate it any futher. This make it impossible to do self reference.
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct ModuleFile {
    pub files: Vec<ModuleFileEntry>,
}

pub struct ModuleFileEntry {
    pub module: Rc<ModuleFile>,
}

fn main() {
    let module = Rc::new(ModuleFile { files: vec![] });

    let entry = ModuleFileEntry {
        module: module.clone(),
    };

    module.files.push(entry);
    /*
    error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Rc` as mutable
    --> ***\src/main.rs:18:5
       |
    18 |     module.files.push(entry);
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
       |
       = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Rc<ModuleFile>`

    For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
    error: could not compile `fuck_around` (bin "fuck_around") due to 1 previous error
    */
}

Internal Mutability and RefCell
Sometime you know that your code will not break the ownership rule, but your compile with static analysis cannot. Thus, we will want to make a contract to the compiler, to promise YOU will not break the ownership rule:

Only one mutable reference, or
One or more immutable reference.


Edit
Unlike in unsafe, RefCell will check and enforce ownership rule at runtime, if your code violate the ownership rule in runtime, it will panic.

If you want you code to be thread safe, you will need to use Arc<Mutex<_>>.
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct ModuleFile {
    pub files: Vec<ModuleFileEntry>,
}

pub struct ModuleFileEntry {
    //          A counted reference
    //          |  that you can mut borrow 
    //          |  |     L> (I pinky promise I will follow ownership rule in runtime, just let me compile)
    //          |  |
    //          v  V
    pub module: Rc<RefCell<ModuleFile>>,
}

fn main() {
    let module = ModuleFile { files: vec![] };
    let module = Rc::new(RefCell::new(module));

    let entry_0 = ModuleFileEntry {
        module: module.clone(),
    };
    let entry_1 = ModuleFileEntry {
        module: module.clone(),
    };

    module.borrow_mut().files.push(entry_0);
    module.borrow_mut().files.push(entry_1);

    let _: &ModuleFileEntry = module
        // immutable borrow
        .borrow()  // `Ref<'_, ModuleFile>`
        .files
        .get(0)
        .unwrap()  // &ModuleFileEntry
        .module
        .borrow()  // `Ref<'_, ModuleFile>` again, multiple immutable borrow is allowed
        .files
        .get(1)
        .unwrap();

    let _: &mut ModuleFileEntry = module
        // mutable borrow
        .borrow_mut()  // `RefMut<'_, ModuleFile>`
        .files
        .get_mut(0)
        .unwrap();

    let _ = module
        // mutable borrow
        .borrow_mut()  // `RefMut<'_, ModuleFile>`
        .files
        .get(0)
        .unwrap()
        .module
        .borrow() // Opss, I break the pinky promise here, panic!
        /*
        thread 'main' panicked at fuck_around\src/main.rs:56:10:
        already mutably borrowed: BorrowError
        note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
        error: process didn't exit successfully: `***.exe` (exit code: 101)
        */
        .files
        .get(1)
        .unwrap();
}


Describing RefCell use as "promise YOU will not break the ownership rule" sounds like you're solely responsible for maintaining the rules normally checked by the compiler. But that's not really the case, as RefCell actually enforces the rules, it just does so with run-time checks and errors/panics in case a rule is broken. Your example makes that point, but the description could be misunderstood, or mistook for the kind of promises made by unsafe code.

Thank you! As a quick question, do the clones reallocate memory?

If I'm not mistaken, only the Rc<_> is cloned, which is only a pointer.
